# How to handle pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-pageradapter

Basically all i have  is tablayout with each tab containing a webview. From the settings menu I enable the user to add or remove tabs. when this is done I need to call pageradapter.notifydatasetchanged(); however doing this all the webview starts to refresh . My question is, Is there a way to avoid this ? I just want the tab to be added or deleted without affecting other tabs.

```
     case "Yahoo":
     if (!fragmentList.contains(fragYahoo)) {
      if (tabYahoo == null) {
       tabYahoo = tabLayout.newTab().setText("Yahoo").setTag("Yahoo");
      }
      tabLayout.addTab(tabYahoo);

      fragYahoo = NewsFragment.newInstance("http://www.Yahoo.com/");
      fragmentList.add(fragYahoo);
      navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.Yahoo).setVisible(true);

     }
     break;
    case "stackoverflow":
     if (!fragmentList.contains(fragstackoverflow)) {
      if (tabstackoverflow == null) {
       tabstackoverflow = tabLayout.newTab().setText("stackoverflow").setTag("stackoverflow");
      }
      tabLayout.addTab(tabstackoverflow);

fragstackoverflow = NewsFragment.newInstance("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
          fragmentList.add(fragstackoverflow);
          navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.stackoverflow).setVisible(true);

         }
       pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

pageradapter initialization

```
 public List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            pagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pagerAdapter.getCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not test, but you can use `TabLayout#setupWithViewPager(viewPager, false);`.

The second parameter is autoRefresh:

```
 * @param autoRefresh whether this layout should refresh its contents if the given ViewPager's
 *                    content changes
```

Comment: I am not using setupwithviewpager , instead this is how i use it          `mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);`

Comment: Please show me the sorce code of initialization of tablayout.

Comment: Update the code as stated I am not using `setupwithviewpager` because it get the job done I think `setupwithviewpager` is newer implementation . Rt now I am trying to save the cache and reload it but can't get it to work . I can't get the logic. I tried all tutorials still stuck

Comment: oh, the updated code is initialization of `ViewPager`.  I want to see the code of initialization of `TabLayout`.  (`setupwithviewpager` is method of `TabLayout`, not of `ViewPager`)

Comment: I am following this example. my own code may be a little rough to understand https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/ . In the fragments I use webview & from the setting tab I add or remove tabs thats all

Comment: I see. unfortunately It is defficult to detect the problem.